# How to debug urllib2 requests via proxy

Tags: python, http, proxy, urllib2

I'm making HTTP requests with Python's urllib2 which go through a proxy.

```
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://myproxy'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
r = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.pbr.com')
```

I'd like to log all headers from this request. I know that using a standard `HTTPHandler` you can do:

```
handler = urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
```

Is there something like this for `ProxyHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `debuglevel` isn't documented.

In practice, it's actually a feature of `httplib` that `urllib2` just forwards along for convenience, so you don't have to pass `lambda: httplib.HTTPConnection(debuglevel=1)` in place of the default `httplib.HTTPConnection` as your HTTP object factory. So, you're unlikely to find anything similar in any of the other handlers.

But if you want to rely on an undocumented feature of the implementation, you're really going to need to [read the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/urllib2.py) to see for yourself.

---

At any rate, the obvious way to add debugging to any of the handlers is to subclass them and do it yourself. For example:

```
class LoggingProxyHandler(urllib2.ProxyHandler):
    def proxy_open(self, req, proxy, type):
        had_proxy = req.has_proxy()
        response = super(LoggingProxyHandler, self).proxy_open(req, proxy, type)
        if not had_proxy and req.has_proxy():
            # log stuff here
        return response
```

I'm relying on internal knowledge that `ProxyHandler` calls `set_proxy` on the request if it doesn't have one and needs one. It might be cleaner to instead examine the *response*… but you may not get all the information you want that way.